# Redis authenticate the client and select the RESP protocol version at the same time

Tags: kotlin, redis, micronaut

I have simple micronuat application and now i'm trying to connect with Redis standalone cluster with below configs

**application.yml**

```
redis:
 uri: redis://redis.dev.com
 port: 6379
 username: db_cache
 password: password
 io-thread-pool-size: 10
 computation-thread-pool-size: 10
 cache:
   expiration-after-write-policy: 1h
 pool:
  enabled: true
  min-idle: 5
  max-total: 15
  max-idle: 10
```

**versions**

```
micronautRedisLettuce = "5.3.2"
micronautVersion = "3.8.1"
```

The application is coming up, but when i hit the health endpoint i'm getting `503` response with below error message with some protocol issue

````
 io.micronaut.management.health.indicator.HealthResult - {} - Health indicator [redis(Primary)] reported exception: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to dbaasprod-re-sppst-dc-107793.dev.target.com/<unresolved>:6379
io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to dbaasprod-re-sppst-dc-107793.dev.target.com/<unresolved>:6379
   at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:350) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:201) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.health.RedisHealthIndicator.healthResultForClient(RedisHealthIndicator.java:107) ~[micronaut-redis-lettuce-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
   at io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.health.RedisHealthIndicator.lambda$getResult$0(RedisHealthIndicator.java:99) ~[micronaut-redis-lettuce-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:386) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:78) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
   at io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.HealthMonitorTask.monitor(HealthMonitorTask.java:98) ~[micronaut-management-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
   at io.micronaut.management.health.monitor.$HealthMonitorTask$Definition$Exec.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[micronaut-management-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
   at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition$DispatchedExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition.java:378) ~[micronaut-inject-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
   at io.micronaut.inject.DelegatingExecutableMethod.invoke(DelegatingExecutableMethod.java:76) ~[micronaut-inject-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
   at io.micronaut.scheduling.processor.ScheduledMethodProcessor.lambda$process$5(ScheduledMethodProcessor.java:127) ~[micronaut-context-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
   at io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeTimer.record(CompositeTimer.java:141) ~[micrometer-core-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
   at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer.lambda$wrap$0(Timer.java:196) ~[micrometer-core-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[?:?]
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[?:?]
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[?:?]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: NOAUTH HELLO must be called with the client already authenticated, otherwise the HELLO AUTH <user> <pass> option can be used to authenticate the client and select the RESP protocol version at the same time
   at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:147) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:116) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:120) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:111) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.complete(CommandWrapper.java:63) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:747) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:682) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
   at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:599) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [RedisURI](https://lettuce.io/core/release/api/io/lettuce/core/RedisURI.html) the urls need to be specified differently based on the cluster type

**URI syntax**

```
Redis Standalone

  * redis://[[username:]password@]host [: port][/database][? [timeout=timeout[d|h|m|s|ms|us|ns]] [ &database=database] [&clientName=clientName] [&verifyPeer=NONE|CA|FULL]]

Redis Standalone (SSL)

  * rediss://[[username:]password@]host [: port][/database][? [timeout=timeout[d|h|m|s|ms|us|ns]] [ &database=database] [&clientName=clientName] [&verifyPeer=NONE|CA|FULL]]

Redis Standalone (Unix Domain Sockets)

 * redis-socket:// [[username:]password@]path[ ?[timeout=timeout[d|h|m|s|ms|us|ns]][&database=database] [&clientName=clientName] [&verifyPeer=NONE|CA|FULL]]

Redis Sentinel

 * redis-sentinel://[[username:]password@]host1 [: port1][, host2 [:port2]][, hostN [:portN]][/ database][? [timeout=timeout[d|h|m|s|ms|us|ns]] [ &sentinelMasterId=sentinelMasterId] [&database=database] [&clientName=clientName] [&verifyPeer=NONE|CA|FULL]]
```

> Redis URIs may contain authentication details that effectively lead to **usernames with passwords, password-only**, or no authentication. Connections are authenticated by using information provided through RedisCredentials. Credentials are obtained at connection time from RedisCredentialsProvider. When configuring username/password on the URI statically, then a StaticCredentialsProvider holds the configured information.

**Notes**

- When using Redis Sentinel, the password from the URI applies to the data nodes only. Sentinel authentication must be configured for each sentinel node.
- Usernames are supported as of Redis 6.

In my case since it's a standalone server i modified the url format to include the password and it worked.

```
uri: redis://password@redis.dev.com
```

For some of the clusters the `username` might be mandatory then you can specify in below format

```
uri: redis://username:password@redis.dev.com
```